# How to fix a security issue raised after reinstalling OS in one new drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, file-permissions

I'm not sure why it must be such secure. After reinstalling the OS in a new SSD, I've recognized that there are many files (in the HDD in the same computer) that seem to have owner missing and I (the current admin) do not have any permission to open it right away (unless I have to update its owner to a new user/group). Here is what it shows when viewing the file/folder Properties:

[image]

I can proceed to change its owner and everything is OK. But the problem here is I have many of such files (maybe thousands or more), so I cannot just `Right click each Properties -> Change each owner to my current account`, it's really a nightmare.

Do you have any tip or trick to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace ownership file-by-file. Change ownership and permissions for the *folder* and propagate to contained objects.

[image: Change owner]

**Use caution, though,** because doing so on certain locations, such as system folders, can make the OS unusable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me a lot :).